# An unhandled exception occurred: The requested module '@angular/compiler' does not provide an export named 'ClassStmt'

Tags: angular, typescript

I just randomly started getting this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred: The requested module
> '@angular/compiler' does not provide an export named 'ClassStmt'

node.js version: 14.17.0

package.json > dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "~13.2.2",
  "@angular/cdk": "^13.0.3",
  "@angular/common": "~13.2.2",
  "@angular/compiler": "~13.2.2",
  "@angular/core": "~13.2.2",
  "@angular/elements": "^13.2.2",
  "@angular/forms": "^13.2.2",
  "@angular/material": "13.0.3",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.2.2",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.2.2",
  "@angular/router": "~13.2.2",
  "tslib": "^2.3.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.11.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.0.4",
  "@angular-eslint/builder": "^13.0.1",
  "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^13.0.1",
  "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^13.0.1",
  "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^13.0.1",
  "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^13.0.1",
  "@angular/cli": "~13.0.4",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.0.0",
  "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
  "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
  "eslint": "^8.3.0",
  "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
  "typescript": "~4.4.3"
}
```

This problem just started happening randomly. I don't see any git diff changes on package-lock.json in the last PR. I'm thinking it has to do with dependency version differences between the angular dependencies. So random!

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I figured it out.

The `@angular/compiler`, `@angular/cli` and `@angular/compiler-cli` dependencies all need to match in version.

After I synced those dependency versions the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue before. To resolve it, you can try the following steps:

Remove the node_modules directory.
Delete the package-lock.json file.
Run npm install to reinstall the dependencies.
Finally, execute ng serve to start the application.